# PHP $_POST emptying

Tags: php, html

I have a really strange problem here..

I have my form:

```
<form class="attach" name="attach" method="post" action="main.php">
    <label for="aurl">URL:</label>
    <input type="text" name="aurl" id="aurl" size="50"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

If I do `print_r($_POST)` I see it fine.

However, if I do, after the `print_r`:

```
if(!empty($_POST['aurl'])) {
     $url = $_POST['aurl'];
```

I can't use `$_POST['aurl']` and `print_r` shows an empty array.

Any idea what could be going on here?

My full code:
http://pastebin.com/Ayt1qCUY

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_POST)` before you implement `empty()`? You need to provide all the code where this occurs. What happens when you try to use `$_POST['aurl']`?

Comment: Show all your code. Something else might be going on.

Comment: Can you post more of your code that is working with the $_POST variable. Seems ok so far.

Comment: You don't need to call `reset()` after the `print_r()`, not that I suspect that as the problem

Comment: @seth Are you literally saying that with 2 `print_r()` calls, in the same page, on the same request, the second one is empty? Is this under if the `if (empty..` block?

Answer (score 1):

If `$_POST['aurl']` has a value of 0, "0", or "", `empty($_POST['aurl'])` will return true. I prefer using `isset($_POST['aurl'])`.

Comment: I was using `isset` originally but tried `empty` because I thought that was causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
echo"url:"; 
print_r($_POST['aurl']); 
die;
```

to see what is in aurl and then use

```
if(isset($_POST['aurl'])) {
 $url = $_POST['aurl'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your POST and GET, please use print_r($_GET); and print_r($_POST); to see all POST and GET you can have in the actionpage ;-)

Answer (score -5):

It's better to use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). If you want to check empty for a string, i recommend to use [strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). empty is problematic for some characters as hughes describes.

Comment: That's not problematic, it's a feature, and it makes perfect sense to have this functionality in `empty` due to the way PHP evalutes `false`.

Comment: But returning true to "0" is completely wrong for it's name. It's string and simply it's not empty! This is why i call it problematic.

Comment: I disagree for the fact that we all know PHP is rubbish. "0" is also false, but you wouldn't suggest not using the `!` operator for boolean checking, would you?